# How to get the current controller instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a controller, that calls another class (say, a mutation) to perform some action. I want to be able to instruct this mutation to interact control flow, e. g. to `redirect_to` or to show `flash` notice. In pseudocode this looks like:

*my_controller.rb*

```
def create
  MyCreateMutation.run!(params).tap do |result|
    render result ? :success : :error
  end
end
```

*my_mutation.rb*

```
def execute **params
  begin
    # do creation
  rescue => e
  # ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
    flash[:error] = e.message
  end
end
```

The problem with the code above is that `flash` is local to current controller. I know, that I can:

- pass current controller instance to a mutation and call `flash` on it;
- declare static `current` method on the very top application controller and use this “global” variable;
- parse a `caller` array and `constantize` the topmost found controller;
- introduce a middleware and save the current controller instance somewhere.

All the above looks like an overkill to me.

**Is there a common way to get the current controller, if it is presented on stack (somewhere on the stack there is a method of `ApplicationController`)**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for future visitors: I finally stuck to declaring `current` class variable on the very top `ApplicationController`:

```
cattr_accessor :current
before_filter { ApplicationController.current = self }
after_filter  { ApplicationController.current = nil  }
```

After that, I have a current controller instance available via:

```
ApplicationController.current
```

Comment: Thanks for this; it is helpful.  I'm curious, why is the `after_filter` (or, `after_action` these days) to set it to `nil` necessary?